# How to determine which button is pressed

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I have a table in which I populate with data from the database. Some of this I have an extra feature of the delete button. But I can't understand how I get that what delete button is pressed in django

```
<tbody>
{% for i in list %}
 <tr>
   <td>{{i.id}}</td>
   <td>{{i.reason}}</td>
   <td>{{i.starting_date}}</td>
   <td>{{i.ending_date}}</td>
   <td>{{i.accept_or_not}}</td>

   {% if i.accept_or_not == 'pending'%}
   <td><input type="button"  name="data_delete_{{i.id}}" value="delete"></td> 
   {%endif%}

 </tr>
{% endfor%}
</tbody>
```

```
def profile_view(request):

    if 'data_delete_id' in request.POST:
    # i don't know how to determine the id in the button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be straight-forward. You can get the name of the button first and then parse the id such as:

```py
def profile_view(request):

    delete_button_id = ""
    for name in request.POST.values():
        if name.startswith('data_delete_'):
            delete_button_id = int(name.split('_')[2])
            break

    # you now have the id in your delete_button_id variable
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django Docs for HttpRequest.POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) your python code has to work as expected because POST returns a dict like Object.

```py
def profile_view(request):

    if 'data_delete_id' in request.POST:
```

But in your template you are using `<input type="button"` .
This will only trigger a client side operation. If you are not having any JS code which you have not shown  here, I would say you need to use `<input type="submit"` instead.

I would also recommend to use `<button type="submit"` instead of `input` because from a semantic perspective it is more accurate.